# iEnvelopes with 2 periods forward - (mql4)

Tags: mql4

I am developing my EA under MQL4. But I need the Envelopes curve is shifted two periods forward. Eg if prices move in time t5, the current value of Envelopes must be that of t3, shifting two periods.

And if I post my problem here it's the only issue I found does not work:

```
int HighLimit = iEnvelopes(NULL, 0.13, MODE_SMA, 0, PRICE_CLOSE, 0.2, MODE_UPPER, -2);
```

How to do it?

Comment: iEnvelopes(NULL, 0`, `13, MODE_SMA, `2 or -2`, PRICE_CLOSE, 0.2, MODE_UPPER, 0); for current bar (shift = 0, for last closed bar shift=1)

Answer (score 0):

You should have the index of that Candle.

```
 int shift = 5;
 double HighLimit = iEnvelopes(NULL, 0.13, MODE_SMA, 0, PRICE_CLOSE, 0.2, MODE_UPPER, Shift-2);
```

Comment: Graphically when you put a negative value in the shift box you will see the Envelopes curve goes to the left of prices/candles. Try it by yourself please, you will understand what I wanted when I posted my question here. So this kind of shift for the left can be reproductible by coding/programming?